# Separating std::initializer_list from parenthesis-enclosed arguments in Ctor invocation

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, constructor

I am writing a simple library in which ease of use and stability is a priority. For example, in my `Mat` (Matrix) class, the current constructor signature is

`Mat<ushort rows, ushort cols> A(std::initializer_list<double>);`

And in practice is very easily readable and understandable:

`Mat<2, 2> A{1, 2, 3, 4};`

This seemed like a good idea at first as I could perform `static_assert` calls to check if an attempt was made to instantiate the Matrix with 0 for the column or row template parameter, but obviously means that I cannot dynamically instantiate Matrix objects.

Ideally, I want to have something along the lines of

`Mat(uchar rows, uchar cols, std::initializer_list<double>)`

*in such a way* that I could instantiate the said object by writing the following:

`Mat A(2, 2) {1, 2, 3, 4};`

I'm not sure how to go about this however, as the initializer list must be enclosed within the parenthesis argument list, which doesn't look nearly as clean:

`Mat A(2, 2, {1, 2, 3, 4});`

Comment: No, you can't alleviate this problem - `std::vector` has exactly the same issue,

Comment: Is it worth sticking to using templates and dealing with the lack of dynamic instantiation, or just bearing with the syntax, in your opinion?

Comment: what is the endgoal? Do you need dynamic instantiation or not? This is something which is articulated as requirements to your library, I have no idea what those are.

Answer (score 1):

I undestrand that you try to avoid use a template, I suggest to define operator= (it's not exactly what you looking for but may be useful)

```
 Mat &operator=(std::initialize_list<int> c);
```

So you can instance you class:

```
 Mat A(2,2);
 A={1,2,3,4};
```